# Is it possible to add a builtin Widget from Ektron to aspx page?

Tags: widget

I want to drag and drop a builtin widget to an aspx page without doing anything inside ektron work area. Can anybody helps me out? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to have created a PageBuilder Wireframe and also will need to be logged in as a CMS user in order to edit the page.

In essence, YES, you can create a page without going into the Workarea.  Use the Ektron Toolbar across the top of the page and select "New".  A step by step wizard will guide you through the rest.

Please [read the documentation](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v9.10/Reference/Web/EktronReferenceWeb.html#PageBuilder/PageBuilder.htm) on Pagebuilder to get a full understanding of what it is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an out-of-the-box Ektron widget as a user control on a standard (non-PageBuilder) template, the no. The default widgets don't have a constructor, default parameter values, or null checks to allow them to run safely outside of the PageBuilder context.

They could be made to run like a standard user control by modifying the original files (which I DO NOT recommend). If you want to go that route, I would recommend copying the original file and modifying the copy.

For specifics, see this post by Joe Mayberry, a developer at Ektron partner [WSOL](http://wsol.com): http://www.ektron.com/Blogs/Joe-Mayberry/A-User-Control-by-Any-Other-Name/